# Set a minimum subtotal amount in Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to Set a minimum order amount of $25. So far i found this code, which seems to be fine for blocking the checkout if minimum is not reached, but the subtotal that it is using is with the tax included and I need to exclude the tax in the total.

---

[image]

---

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 25;

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax
```

This will give you the WooCommerce Cart subtotal excluding tax

Source: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#48-49

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! I searched everywhere online and couldn't find this simple line of code to exclude the tax.

Comment: @bworkman You bet! Glad it worked. API source docs are always a sure bet, just takes some time to dig up and test.