# Adding Product to Checkout Automatically if Sub-Total is Over £100

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I found this great piece of code that allows me to automatically add a product to the checkout if the total is over £100. However I would like to change it to where a product is added if the sub total is over £100. This is because I want to exclude vat and shipping costs

```
// ADD PRODUCT TO CHECKOUT IF ORDER IS £100 OR OVER

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $product_id = 4980; //replace with your product id
        $found = false;
        $cart_total = 100; //replace with your cart total needed to add above item

        if( $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= $cart_total ) {
            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                        $found = true;
                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found )
                    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856956/10447197) will be useful to you.

Comment: sorry this does not work

Comment: Could you show the code you used based on the link in my comment?

Comment: Hi Vincenzo, thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay in communications. As requested I have provided the code below. I think it is working, but it needs double checking

Comment: add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $product_id = 4980;
  $found = false;
  $cart_total= 100; 

  if( $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax>= $cart_total ) {
   //check if product already in cart
   if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
     $_product = $values['data'];
     if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id

Comment: $found = true;
    }

    if ( ! $found )
     $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
   } else {

    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: Sorry had to provide it in 2 comments

Comment: You should edit/add the code in your question and not insert it in the comments. If you want to keep your old code in the question you can add a new paragraph with the code you modified according to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856956/10447197) in my comment. Also you should remove the code in the comment. By inserting the code in the question it is more readable and above all it is not broken. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Vincenzo thank you for your comment. As you requested I made the change in the old code but essentially I replaced if( $woocommerce->cart->cart_total>= $cart_total )  with if( $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= $cart_total ). That seems to have done the trick